# Use an index to get the value in a div containing multiple rows (divs)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container div and within that div I have some rows like this:

```
<div id="containerDiv1">
    <div class="paramRow">
        <input type="text" value="Foo" id="param1" />
    </div>
    <div class="paramRow">
        <input type="text" value="Bar" id="param2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to get all the paramRow divs within the containerDiv1 and then select a paramRow div by its index.

```
$(function(){
    var containerDiv = $('#containerDiv1');
    var paramRows = containerDiv.find('.paramRow');

    // Below should output "Foo"
    alert($(paramRows.get(0) + ' #param1').val());

    // Below should output "Bar"
    alert($(paramRows.get(1) + ' #param2').val());
});
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Uncaught error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object
>   HTMLDivElement] #param1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, `get()` returns a native DOMElement, not a jQuery object. Also, you can't append a jQuery object and a string to form a selector.

You should use `eq()` to get the jQuery object containing an element by index, then `find()` to get the `input` within it. Try this:

```js
var $containerDiv = $('#containerDiv1');
var $paramRows = $containerDiv.find('.paramRow');

// Below should output "Foo"
alert($paramRows.eq(0).find('#param1').val());

// Below should output "Bar"
alert($paramRows.eq(1).find('#param2').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerDiv1">
  <div class="paramRow">
    <input type="text" value="Foo" id="param1" />
  </div>
  <div class="paramRow">
    <input type="text" value="Bar" id="param2" />
  </div>
</div>
```